# Logging inside OperationSequenceComponent

Tags: microsoft-commerce-server

I need to add logging  inside existing OperationSequenceComponent, I can use Debug.Write("") to write information into debug stream.

But I'm wondering if there any possibility to log into file or database into  OperationSequenceComponent ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have not read through it in its entirety, first read through the original Microsoft Commerce Server 2009 Documentation on Logging, Tracing and Exception management for the Commerce Foundation. It is available off of msdn [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd451660.aspx)